# VNC (or RDP) server using outbound connection only

Tags: remote-desktop, firewall, vnc, udp

How do I set up a VNC server that connects to an intermediary server to start an outbound communication, that can be used by a VNC client.

This way the port forwarding doesn't need to be set up, and firewall rules for inbound connections are not required.

I've seen some commercial software do this (I believe using some flavour of VNC)

IS there any VNC that does this easily?

Answer (score 0):

They actually frown on software suggestions here. Anyways, you're looking from something like [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/UK/).